# How to get cosine in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working in jupyter notebook, and I am getting the error that cos is not defined, I imported pandas and numpy. Is there any other library I am missing?

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-cos-function/amp/ probably `math`

Comment: Have you googled "python cosine function"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import numpy or pandas (which as far as I am aware doesn't implement any general-purpose cosine function) to calculate cosine. You can import math and then use math.cos().

Answer (score -1):

Check the [numpy cosine](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html) documentation.

One possible mistake could be something this simple:

```
import numpy
np.cos(something) # Error. Not defined!
```

This will not work, because the function is actually `numpy.cos` and in most examples, numpy is renamed as 'np'.

Instead, try:

```
import numpy as np
np.cos(something)
```

Or,

```
import numpy
numpy.cos(something)
```

Comment: `numpy.cosine()` isn't defined.

Comment: Oh wow. Nick, that took me so long to realize that I typed it incorrectly. Thank you.